# ASP.NET MVC5 I don't want to merge CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, iis

I know that merging CSS files can affect possitivly the performance of the Website but in my case I have the following scenario.

I have 4 color themes for my ASP.NET application

1. Default
2. Red
3. Purple
4. Green

I wrote a bit of javascript that enables or disables stylesheets on the website

```
$("link[href='/Content/Style.css']").removeAttr('disabled');
$("link[href='/Content/Purple.css']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Works perferct when I am debugging the project locally.

The problem is when I publish to IIS.

Obviously IIS merges the CSS files in to one single file (see below) and my javascript does not work since it cannot find the CSS links.

```
<link href="/Content/styles?v=LJz1gcJyVEK_Atj5S7zoyR1lIdMwZ5IJIZn8ff329wQ1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way to say to IIS to not merge CSS files?

Or is do you have any better suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: IIS doesn't merge CSS, ASP.NET does. You need to look at your `Bundling.cs` file and remove the necessary files from the style bundle. You'll also need to update your layout to add these files in manually

Comment: You can have couple bundles created with the color themes

Comment: RGaham thank you, this actually worked, I removed the styles from my Bundle and hardcoded them in the _Layout.

Comment: @Morpheus you mean I create one Bundle per theme.

And then I use Javascript to enable/disable the Bundle?

Comment: @Christos312 exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, you should have an `App_Start/Bundling.cs` file with something similar to this:

```
Bundle css = new StyleBundle("~/Content/styles");
css.IncludeDirectory("~/Content/", "*.css", true);
```

This takes all the CSS files from the content directory and bundles them into a single CSS file. Not only does this bundle the files together, but it also *minifies* them, so it's worth integrating your themes into this, something like:

```
string[] themes = { "Default", "Red", "Purple", "Green" };
foreach (var themeName in themes)
{
    Bundle cssTheme = new StyleBundle("~/Theme/" + themeName);
    cssTheme.Include("~/Theme/" + themeName + ".css");
    bundleCollection.Add(cssTheme );
}
```

That will create one *bundle* for each one of your themes. Then, in your `_Layout.cshtml` you can render the bundles like so:

```
@{
    string[] themes = { "Default", "Red", "Purple", "Green" };
}
@Styles.Render(themes.Select(theme => "~/Theme" + theme).ToArray())
```

When this renders, you'll see the following HTML printed out:

```
<link href="/Theme/Default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Theme/Red" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Theme/Purple" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Theme/Green" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Allowing you to use your existing Javascript, like:

```
$("link[href^='/Theme/Default']").removeAttr('disabled');
$("link[href^='/Theme/Purple']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

*Note the use of the [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), as in production ASP.NET will append a unique querystring onto the end of your theme name*